# Помогите красиво перестроить предложение

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите красиво перестроить предложение:

> Смотри, кто хороший человек, кто достоин быть другом тебе и творит
>   тебе добро, тому и открывай свою душу, а те, кто обрывает лепестки и
>   топчет ногами — те, которых ты видишь, что они грубы, непорядочны и
>   неблагодарны — от тех уходи, и ни в чем им не помогай!

Особенно смущает "те, которых ты видишь, что они грубы".

Comment: Вот как это выгядит в оригинале: -----Водя девушку по саду, мудрец сказал:
 - ...Так и ты будь подобна цветку: раскрывай свое сердце перед людьми не спеша, незаметно. Смотри, кто достоин быть другом тебе и творит тебе добро, как поливает цветок водой, а кто обрывает лепестки и топчет ногами. (Татьяна Рыжова. Кружево судьбы. Сила Вселенной в женских руках)------А в вашей фразе лепестки притянуты за уши и  нагромождение слов в одном предложении чрезмерное.

Answer (score 0):

Обращай внимание на хороших, простых людей, тех, которые дарят тебе улыбку, и исключай из жизни тех, кто груб к тебе. Не позволяй топтать ногами лепестки твоей души.

Answer (score 0):

Замечай, кто хороший человек, кто достоин быть другом тебе и творит тебе добро, тому и открывай свою душу, а от тех,  кто обрывает "лепестки души и топчет ногами", от людей грубых, непорядочных и неблагодарных, — от тех уходи и ни в чем им не помогай!

Comment: Может быть второе «от тех» убрать?

Comment: Здесь повтор, наверное, использован как средство художественной выразительности. Это и лексический повтор, и  нужный элемент для структуры предложения, оправдывающий увеличенную паузу и постановку тире.

Comment: Ok. Только почему «наверное»? Вы же использовали.

Comment: Ну да, я старалась сохранить по возможности авторский текст.